# Android Studio not checking anymore if variable should be final after using Java 8

Tags: java, android, java-8

Before I used Java 8 in Android Studio, the following code is marked as an error:

```
String str = "a non-final string";
vVerse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSomething(str);
    }
});
```

Now, after I enabled Java 8, Android Studio does not mark it as an error anymore, regardless if I used lambda or an anonymous class.

Should I be worried?

Comment: I'd guess it's checking for effective final-ness. If you do change it somewhere else (i.e. `str = "a different string"`), it'll probably give an error.

Comment: I don't sure because I didn't use Java 8 yet. But are u try to check studio settings for Java?

Comment: @Mshnik Yes if you change it's valueinside the `onClick()` than it gives an error.

Comment: Does the code compile? If yes, then it's correct code in Java 8. Java 8 compiler is smarter and works with a snapshot of the value inside the anonymous class without having to explicitly the variable is final.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
vVerse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            str="asdkfjdf";
            doSomething(str);
        }
    });
```

It will give you error now! It's seems like a feature!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, Java 8 checks for the effective finality of the local variable, unlike in the past where you have to explicitly declare the variable as final.